# Defining XML output for operator

Tags: htlatex

I am converting LaTeX to docbook with the following command

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,docbook-mml" " -cunihtf" "-cdocbk"
```

Now, unfortunately, the `\cdot` operator gets lost during translation. (It simply disappears.)

How can I define an XML sequence that should be emitted for every `\cdot` in the source file?

Answer (score 5):

If you compile just with

```
 htlatex filename "xhtml,docbook-mml"
```

you'll get this `mathml`:

```xml
<inlineequation  
role="inline" ><!--l. 7--><math 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>2</mn> <mo 
class="MathClass-bin">&sdot;</mo> <mn>2</mn></math> </inlineequation>
```

you can see that `&sdot;` entity is there. running `xmllint` tells us that this entity is undefined:

```
sample.xml:16: parser error : Entity 'sdot' not defined
class="MathClass-bin">&sdot;</mo> <mn>2</mn></math> </inlineequation>
```

this entity is removed from your document using `xtpipes` post-processing (invoked by `-cdocbk` option). So the solution we need to find is to include the `cdot` as either numeric entity, or direct unicode value. We can try to use different conversion table to unicode than one invoked by `-cunihtf`. from `tex4ht` [manual](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-37)

> The mzlatex command is a short cut representation for the command
>   ‘htlatex filename "xhtml,mozilla" " -cmozhtf" "-cvalidate"’. It take
>   into account special needs of browsers. The xhmlatex command is a
>   short cut representation for the command ‘htlatex filename
>   "xhtml,mathml" " -cunihtf" "-cvalidate"’; it does not make any
>   compromizes toward browsers.

so we can try to replace `-cunihtf` with `-cmozhtf`:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,docbook-mml" " -cmozhtf" "-cdocbk"
```

and the result seems to be fine:

```xml
<inlineequation role="inline"><!--l. 7
--><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mn>2</mn> <mo class="MathClass-bin">&#x22C5;</mo> <mn>2</mn></math> </inlineequation>
```

Comment: Can I somehow define a conversion table myself?

Comment: @JohnB yes, copy file `texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/mozilla/charset/unicode.4hf` to your working dir and modify it according to your needs